# Stop dialogflow from sending a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is there a way to stop dialogflow from replying any of the responses added in the dialogflow console using the nodejs SDK?

I have created a few intents, which have each their own responses. Now I want to add a sort of handover functionality through a fulfillment webhook.

Basically it should work like this: when the user asks for a human to chat, the API stores the session and any new call should check if the session is marked as "waiting for human". If it is, then no reply should be send by dialogflow any longer. In this way, the *human* can chat without interruptions. If the session is not marked, then a the regular responses should be sent. So here's the question: how can I avoid dialogflow from sending any of the responses without moving the responses to the API?

Thank you in advance